# Copying binary data between databases changes the content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Using Rails 5.1. I have a utility that copies records from tables in one database into the same tables in another database (the target database has the same tables and layout as the source database). I'm using code like this:

```
select_cmd = BookCover.where(user_id: 1)
records = @from_database.connection.select_all(select_cmd.to_sql).to_a
created_records = BookCover.create!(records)
```

And the problem I'm getting is that in the source database, if I look at the image field I see:

```
irb(main):033:0> BookCover.first.image[0..10]
=> "\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00"
```

In the target database, I'm seeing:

```
irb(main):029:0> BookCover.first.image[0..10]
=> "\\377\\330\\37"
```

You can see that not only does the representation look different, instead of storing "xFF" as a single character it is storing it as "\377" (four characters). It seems like `select_all` is somehow doing something different to the Postgres ***bytea*** field. I'm using `select_all` because there are no models to back the tables in the from_database so I can't use standard model-based ARel methods to retrieve the data. How can I retrieve the record from the "from" database without having the data transformed by the `select_all` call.

Comment: have you confirmed that the databases are identically configured, in all respects? This looks like an encoding difference. I would suggest using `pg_dump`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html

Comment: Have you confirmed that the actual image is different (original vs. copy)? If there's an encoding difference, ActiveRecord may be able to accommodate and produce the same image.

Comment: I have confirmed that when using a select_all the image binary data comes out differnet than if I just used an ARel. Once that happens, the target data will be different, because the data being stored is to the same. And I've confirmed that the target is no longer a valid image.

Comment: My suggestion is to debug by eliminating as many factors as possible.  So eliminate Ruby/Rails/Arel and do this in postgresql. If that also fails, you can focus on the db config, and ignore Ruby etc for the time being.

Comment: 1) Are the databases the same version and running on same OS? 2)  What is the value for [bytea_output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT)  set to in each database's postgresql.conf?

Comment: Note that the non-printable values in the first output are in hex and the in the second are in octal: `\xFF` = `\377' and `\xD8` = `\330`. I suspect the issue is that ActiveRecord doesn't know how to handle the value of `image` returned by executing the raw SQL query, and therefore defaults to handling it as text. This text content is then transformed again prior to being saved in the second table. Instead of using `to_a` with the raw SQL query results, try using `cast_values`. I've encountered similar issues in the past and that approach adequately addressed them.

Comment: I'm closing this out without an answer because I've realized the question is so poorly worded that everyone (except maybe @JohnH) has missed the point.

Comment: Does your `book_covers` table use sequential IDs as the primary key? Since no ordering is provided, maybe you are comparing the binary field of two different records.